# Angularjs ui-grid events not removed per row after data update

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a grid that contains an edit button per each row. Everything works as expected the first time the page is loaded, but if I try to add a new entity and repopulate the grid, the edit button will fire the edit event of the first already existing entity.

This is my code:

```
    var columnDefs = [
      {
        name: '', field: 'id',
        cellTooltip: 'Edit',
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnMenu: false,
        enableCellEdit: false,
        maxWidth: 30,
        headerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-icon"></div>',
        cellEditableCondition: false,
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-icon"><div title="Edit" class="ui-edit ui-grid-icon-pencil" ng-click="grid.appScope.editNews({{row.entity.id}})"></div></div>'
      },
      { name: 'shortDescription', field: 'shortDescription' }];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableGridMenu: false,
    enableSorting: false,
    enableRowHashing: false,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    data: "data",
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };

  var getData = function () {
    showLoading('.grid');

    newsRepository.resourceFunctions.query(displayOptions,
      function (data) {
        if (data.length == 0) {
          setEmptyGrid($scope, 'There are no news!');
          $scope.data = [{
            "message": 'There are no news!'
          }];
        }
        else {
          setGrid(data);
        }

        hideLoading('.grid');
      }, //success
      function (error) {
        $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
        hideLoading("#view-container");
        toaster.pop('error', "Server error",
          "There was an error while processing your request. Please contact support.", 10000);
      }); //error
  };

  function setGrid(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
    $scope.data = data;
  }
```

This is how the grid is re-populated (the data is comming from the save AJAX request):

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
setGrid(data.items);
```

The edit event is inside the cellTemplate: grid.appScope.editNews({{row.entity.id}}). Also, after the grid data is updated, this template is populated with the correct entity id, but the editNews is called with the id of the older entity. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this today, although more to do with `cellTemplate` buttons not shifting to their correct row when a new row was added, or an existing row removed.

In your particular case just remove the `{{` and `}}` in your call to editNews. E.g. it should be:

`ng-click="grid.appScope.editNews(row.entity.id)"`. This worked nicely for me.